# Problem with refcheck

Tags: bibliographies, refcheck

The following code does not do what it should:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{1111}

%% This works:
\bibitem[Ccc]{FP}
The Frog, Kermit, and Piggy, Miss.
\newblock Sesame Street.

%% This does not work:
\bibitem[CCC]{FP2}
The Frog, Kermit, and Piggy, Miss.
\newblock Sesame Street.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I get the follwing error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\bibitem ...$}}\@@@biblabel@@ }\fi }\ifx #1\@nil 
                                                  \@@bibitem@@ {#2}\else \@@...
l.14 \bibitem[CCC]{FP2}
```

It seems that `refcheck` has a problem with certain optional labels in `\bibitem`.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### UPDATE

The issue has been solved in version 1.9.1 of `refcheck.sty` (14 February, 2013)

---

### Original answer (still valid for `refcheck` version 1.9)

Nasty bug in `refcheck`. Here's how `refcheck.sty` redefines `\bibitem`:

```
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][\@nil]{%
 \@ifundefined{cit@#2}{%
  \@warning@rc@{Unused bibitem `#2' on page \thepage}%
  \if@show@cite
    \gdef\@biblabel{\makebox[0pt][r]{\zero@height{{\mark@size{\bfseries\upshape?}}%
      \underline{\@verbatim@{#2}}{\mark@size{\bfseries\upshape?}}$\,$}}%
      \@@@biblabel@@
    }%
  \fi
 }{%
  \if@show@cite
    \set@fbox@par
    \gdef\@biblabel{\makebox[0pt][r]{\zero@height{\fbox{\@verbatim@{#2}}$\,$}}\@@@biblabel@@}%
  \fi
 }%
 \ifx#1\@nil\@@bibitem@@{#2}%
 \else\@@bibitem@@[#1]{#2}%
 \fi
}%
```

The problem is in the final part: any entry where the first two letters in the optional argument are equal will trigger the error. Let's see why. The code is

```
 \ifx#1\@nil\@@bibitem@@{#2}%
 \else\@@bibitem@@[#1]{#2}%
 \fi
```

and when you have

```
\bibitem[Ccc]{FP}
```

the argument `#1` is `Ccc`; thus the conditional

```
\ifx Ccc\@nil
```

is false and everything up to `\else` is skipped. In the case of

```
\bibitem[CCC]{FP2}
```

TeX finds

```
\ifx CCC\@nil
```

and the conditional is *true*, so `\@nil` should be expanded, which can't because it's purposely left undefined by the LaTeX kernel.

What does the package want to do? It wants to check whether an optional argument is not specified, and this is the *wrong* way to do it. Here's a better version:

```
\usepackage{refcheck}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{%
 \@ifundefined{cit@#2}{%
  \@warning@rc@{Unused bibitem `#2' on page \thepage}%
  \if@show@cite
    \gdef\@biblabel{\makebox[0pt][r]{\zero@height{{\mark@size{\bfseries\upshape?}}%
      \underline{\@verbatim@{#2}}{\mark@size{\bfseries\upshape?}}$\,$}}%
      \@@@biblabel@@
    }%
  \fi
 }{%
  \if@show@cite
    \set@fbox@par
    \gdef\@biblabel{\makebox[0pt][r]{\zero@height{\fbox{\@verbatim@{#2}}$\,$}}\@@@biblabel@@}%
  \fi
 }%
 \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\@@bibitem@@{#2}%
 \else\@@bibitem@@[#1]{#2}%
 \fi
}
}% End of \AtBeginDocument
\makeatother
```

A non e-TeX way could be

```
\ifx\valign#1\valign
```

instead of the better

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
```

Take your pick.

Comment: I know I shall not comment with "Thank you", but rather upvote and accept the answer. But that does not seem enough. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a chance that this change will be made to the package?

Comment: @soandos I don't think the author is still active on it. :(